# Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland Cannot Run Firefox with root/ sudo

Tags: firefox, 22.04, .desktop, wayland

I would like to run a browser with root access.

However, when I run: `sudo firefox`, it shows:

```
sudo firefox
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

I try to change the session as root with `sudo su -` and run `firefox`, but it will give the same error.

I use Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome with Wayland.

For context:
I need to run the browser as root because it will need to launch an agent (F5 VPN client). Currently, without root access, the VPN agent only run as current user, and it seems the agent doesn't have enough permission to read/ change pc configuration (I don't know exactly, F5 support tell me like this). Thus, I need to run the browser as root.

I cannot use the f5fpc client (cli client) as our VPN use 2FA, the only way to connect to the VPN is via browser authentication (and it will install some agent).

Comment: Why do you want to run the browser as root? As a workaround, try using the deb version of firefox instead of the snap version.

Comment: Xorg didn't restrict root; Wayland does for security reasons (*root should be used to maintain a system, not be end-users*).  Most modern apps should not be run as root, even `google-chrome` rejects that (*unless you specifically disable certain security features*). Your request makes little sense unless you've malicious intentions or are misguided, so I'd re-examine what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi everyone, I need to run the browser as root because it will need to launch an agent (F5 VPN client). Currently, without root access, the VPN agent only run as current user, and it seems the agent doesn't have enough permission to read/ change pc configuration (I don't know exactly, F5 support tell me like this). Thus, I need to run the browser as root.

Comment: Added more context on the post.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a solution for you. However, note that running a browser as root sound like a terrible idea.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you can launch your VPN agent as root without launching the browser, and then use your browser normally. But I never used F5 VPN, hence the 1% of doubt ;-).